# how to pluralize with template tag

Tags: python, django

I forgot this, there was an easy built in template tag I could use.

```
{{ post.comment_set.count }}comment
```

if there's more than one comment then it should display comments.

```
{{ post.comment_set.count|"something here" }}comment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [**`|pluralize`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#pluralize) here:

```
{{ post.comment_set.count }}comment{{ post.comment_set.count|pluralize }}
```

That being said, please do *not* write business logic in the templates, you better *annotate* your `posts` with the number of comments. This is also not good performance-wise, since you make an extra query *per* `post` object.

You can annotate your `Post` queryset, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Post.objects.annotate(
    ncomment=Count('comment')
)
```

and then in the template, you can write:

```
{{ post.ncomment }}comment{{ post.ncomment|pluralize }}
```